# Finding length of arc RWT

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

I am confused on how do you calculate the arc angle of arc RWT

Comment: What do you know about the geometry of circles that might help you answer this? Also, what can you figure out from the diagram?

Comment: You'll be much more likely to get help if you [show that you've made an attempt to solve the problem or share what you know](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). We're happy to help you along, but we won't do your work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect $O$ with $R, S, T$. $OR=OS=OT$, therefore $\triangle{ORS} \cong \triangle{OST}$  (SSS). They are also isosceles triangles so $\angle{OSR} \cong \angle{OST}=120°/2=60°$. Apparently $\triangle{ORS}$ and $\triangle{OST}$ are equilateral. Thus, $m\angle{ORT}=120°$ and arc $RST$ has the same measure. Can you solve it now?